# Angular2 Pass data between two components via service

Tags: angular, service, components

Hi I'm trying to pass selected value(from options) from first component to second component but I am having trouble getting the values in second component.

I am currently using services to do so and am console.logging everythign to see if I'm passing the value.

Everything loads as I intend until second component.

Below is my code

First Component HTML

```
 <p class="fonts-title"> Select Region</p>
 <div class="selectcontainer">
    <select (change)="passValue1()" formControlName="region" class="form- control"  class="selectionbox" [(ngModel)]="selected_region" required> 
  <option *ngFor="let region of regions | filterregion" [ngValue]="region"> 
{{region.areaName}}
</option>
</select>
```

First Component

```
export class SearchSelectComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private passData: TeacherPassDataService) { }

  selected_region: string;

  passValue1(val1) {
    this.passData.setValue1(val1=this.selected_region['areaCode'])
  }
```

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class TeacherPassDataService {

    value1: string;

    constructor() { 
        this.value1="",
    }

    setValue1(val1: string) {
        this.value1 = val1
        console.log(this.getValue1()) //this prints selected_region value from the first component as I intented
    }

    getValue1() {
        return this.value1;
    }

}
```

However, in second component,

```
constructor(
        private getVal: TeacherPassDataService) {
    }

   getVal1() {
       return this.getVal.getValue1(),
       this.firstVal=this.getVal1(),
       console.log(this.getVal.getValue1()) //this prints 'undefined'
    }
```

Why I am getting undefined in the second component when I am setting the value correctly using service?

Please Help!

Thank you in advance

Comment: where is `TeacherPassDataService` set as provider?

Comment: I tried removing value1="" from the constructor , it didn't work!

Comment: And I added TeacherPassDataService to the provider

Comment: @Lea as suraj said where do you provide `TeacherPassDataService` ? Like `providers: [TeacherPassDataService]`

Comment: yeah just like that!

Comment: in app.module.ts or your component?

Comment: No in the component decorator I added provider so I've removed that and added provider in app.module.ts, now I am getting 

    Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Actually I fixed it by adding providers in app.module.ts thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are not adding the service as a Provider inside the appModule,

```
@NgModule({
 providers: [
 TeacherPassDataService 
 ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the attached working plunkr. I have tried to mimic your use case. It uses routing to load the second component. I believe it should answer your question. Please have a look - 
https://plnkr.co/edit/w7A8RJeFPYq5rstTfXYF?p=preview

I have used following in the TeacherPassDataService-

```
this.router.navigate(["/secondComponent"]);
```